# RestEasy - ClientResponse.ReleaseConnection()

Tags: java, rest, response, resteasy

Why do I need to release the ClientResponse with:

```
 response.releaseConnection();
```

Is there an advantage? Why doesnt RestEasy handle this?

Sometimes I have to release it, sometimes I havnt - whats the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Resteasy will release the connection under the covers. The only
>   counterexample is the case in which the response is an instance of
>   InputStream, which must be closed explicitly.

You can read more about this in the [RESTEasy documentation.](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#transport_layer)

Comment: Doc also says "If some version of the overloaded method ClientResponse.getEntity() is called, then Resteasy will release the connection (unless the entity is an instance of InputStream). If the entity is ignored, then the connection must be released explicitly".

Comment: @eiden -1 since you've quoted a special case which doesn't seem relevant for the question that uses `ClientResponse`, please correct me if I'm mistaken or update the answer

Comment: @Love It's relevant. Read the original question again.

Comment: @eiden, I did. Your quote suggest that a connection never needs to be released explicitly. Nor do you say anything about the advantage. In fact, looking in the documentation it seems the quote is not about `ClientResponse`at all, the following paragraph seems more relevant: *...if the result of an invocation is an instance of ClientResponse, then one of two additional steps must be taken to release the connection...*.